# Display loading message for long running process

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Write("<div id=\"loading\" style=\"position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center; top:300px;\"><img src=\"https://site here/images/loading.gif\" border=0></div>");
            Response.Flush();
            LoadDirs();
            Response.Write("<script>document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';</script>");
        }
    }
```

LoadDirs() builds a List< TreeNode > and then adds them to the TreeView.

It seems the 2nd Write to clear the loading image happens right away.
I don't want the loading image to disappear until LoadDirs() is completely finished.

Comment: Ummm..you have to use ajax for something like this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704171/asp-net-display-loading-message-while-update-panel-is-updating

Comment: Is there a way to trigger it on Page_Load and not a button press?

Comment: For Page_Load, I think your best bet is to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911059/asp-net-3-5-display-updateprogress-during-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) and [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

An introduction here => [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386421(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to trigger it on Page_Load and not a button press?

Comment: Yes, with jQuery you can set a bunch of things to happen once the page has completed it's load, including invoking a PageMethod to retrieve some data from the server in the background.